# MongoDB Ops Manager - CPU Time - No data available

Tags: mongodb, monitoring

We have 5 groups and enabled on all groups monitoring agent. We use `Ops Manager 1.6.2.251`.

All metrics get collected and are available in a nice graph.
CPU Time is not available on all groups. Our VMs are OpenStack based with RHEL7.

[image]

Howto debug that? Found nothing relevant to CPU time in `/opt/mongodb/mms/logs`

Comment: Have you checked wether munin collects the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have [munin-node](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/munin-node) installed, configured and reachable (on port 4949) by the MMS agents in order for CPU and other system data to be collected.  This is all covered in [the documentation](https://docs.cloud.mongodb.com/tutorial/configure-monitoring-munin-node/).

Comment: Since then, the documentation you linked added the note `As of Automation Agent 2.7.0, hardware monitoring using munin-node is deprecated.`.

Comment: this was answered over 2 years ago, and the product has moved on (a lot) since then (as have I - I have not used it for roughly that long), so unless you are running something really old I don't think this would apply to a current installation